# PublishOn Reactor Asynchronous Flux and thread locking

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'm trying to build a scenario which follows theses steps:

1. (on `Init`) `Flux` publisher created
2. (on `Init`) Subscribers `subscribe`
3. (on user action) publisher start streaming/publishing events
4. Web controller subscriber consumes and caches last `BUFFER_SIZE` events

Based on http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#advanced-parallelizing-parralelflux and https://www.baeldung.com/reactor-core I'm trying to use `create` and `publish` to do this, and the issue I'm having is that the thread that calls `flux.connect` is trapped in the while loop inside the publisher.

Here is a minimal working example using `spring-boot-starter-webflux`:

```
private ConnectableFlux<Integer> flux;
private Scheduler scheduler;
private int nextRead = 0;

private static final int BUFFERSIZE = 100;
private List<Integer> sink = new LinkedList<Integer>() ;

@PostConstruct
public void Init() {
    this.scheduler = Schedulers.newSingle("Streamer");

    flux = Flux.<Integer>create(fluxSink -> {
        while (true) {
            fluxSink.next(nextRead++);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).publishOn(scheduler).publish();
}

@GetMapping("/subscribe")
public void subscribe(){
    this.flux.subscribeOn(scheduler,false).subscribe(new CoreSubscriber<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Context currentContext() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
            subscription.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer e) {
            while (sink.size() >= BUFFERSIZE) sink.remove(0);
            sink.add(e);
            logger.debug("sink event: " + e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {}

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {}
    });
}

@GetMapping("/start")
public void startStream(){
    logger.debug("EventStreamSimulator startStream before connect");
    this.flux.connect();
    logger.debug("EventStreamSimulator startStream after connect");
}

@GetMapping("/values")
public Flux<Integer> getEvents(){
    return Flux.fromIterable(sink);
}
```

Based on this code, the web request on `/start` will start the streaming but the `http` thread will be stuck in the emitter infinite loop. requests on `/values` and logging shows that it is working fine though (but the original `http request` to `/start` never finishes/returns)

Sample logs:

> 2018-10-09 18:12:54.798 DEBUG 6024 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] com.example.FluxPocController            : emmit event: 0
>
> 2018-10-09 18:12:54.798 DEBUG 6024 --- [     Streamer-1] com.example.FluxPocController            : sink event: 0

**Then**, here is the question:  is the `publishOn` directive supported for these async way of using `Flux.create`? if so, how to use it?

Comment: not sure what you are trying to achieve here, infinite loop without exit condition is definitely not a good idea; especially as it here basically hogs 1/4 of your available CPUs... publishOn influences where the data is emitted once produced, and the create itself is the production stage so publishOn has no influence there

Comment: As I'm very new on reactive programming, so I might be on a http://xyproblem.info/. But as both references kind of suggest a infinite loop as valid, I'm confused. And if I do something as `Flux.range(1, 1000000).publishOn(Schedulers.newSingle("Streamer-b")).subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {...` in a http request, the http threads moves on and is not trapped in the long range emit loop. I guess I'm having a hard time to understand the PublishOn use case then. Will try some more combinations to try to understand. Any reference suggestion?

Comment: to learn a bit about publishon, maybe this talk can help: https://vimeo.com/291358417. be sure to read up the reference documentation and look at more introductory talks as well before. hope this helps a bit